# let PHP get value from prompt box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am really new to PHP and I basically want php to get the data from a prompt box.
Can someone help me with it? Right now I just have the javascript code:

```
var name;
var person = prompt ("May I ask your name?");
if (person!=null && person!="") {
    name = person;
} else {
    name = "Anonymous";
}
```

The variable 'name' is what I am trying to get in PHP

Thanks!

Comment: PHP can't access values from Javascript directly - you'll need to use AJAX or something to post the data to a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the name to the php page.  Javascript is run in the browser and PHP is run on the server.

A simple way would be to take the value set it as a value in a hidden form and call the `submit` event on the form.  Since you said that you are new to php and javascript.  Otherwise you would send the data via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP ..

```
<form method="post" name="formname">
    <input name="inputname" type="text" />
</form>
```

to get the var

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputname']);
```